# Appending a .txt document with contents of clipboard using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

```
!w::
Sendinput ^c ; copy selection
Sleep 1000 ; gives time for the copy to work
FileAppend, `n`n%clipboard%, C:\Users\John Salter\ToAnki.txt; Add clipboard content to the end of a text file. Insert 2 new lines before inserting the clipboard with `n`n
Return
```

This is the script I've been trying to use. I was concerned about the space in between "John" and "Salter" so tried it in other locations but it still doesn't work.

I get no error messages.

The content of the the clipboard is altered, so the problem lies beneath the second line.

The use of FileAppend would seem to work looking at the help documentation.

Can anybody figure out what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A **[comment flag](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_CommentFlag.htm#Remarks)** **that appears on the same line as a command** is
>   not considered to mark a comment unless it **has at least one space or
>   tab to its left**.

```
FileAppend, `n`n%clipboard%, C:\Users\John Salter\ToAnki.txt ; Add clipboard content to the end of a text file. Insert 2 new lines before inserting the clipboard with `n`n
```

Comment: This corrected the problem and the script now works as intended. Thank you!